# ¿Como puedo agregar datos de entrada desde un archivo .txt a un array en C?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente programa para poder leer datos desde un archivo.txt y pasarlos a un array, quiero hacerlo utilizando CMD de windows de la siguiente forma: lee_datos < datos_entrada.txt.

y el codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void lee_datos(int *array,int N);
void imprime_datos(int *array,int N);

int main(){
    int N = 5;
    int array[N];

    //llenamos el array con los datos de entrada
    lee_datos(array,N);

    //comprobacion
    
    printf("El array es: ");
    imprime_datos(array,N);

    return 0;
}

void lee_datos(int *array,int N){
    int i;
    int dato;
    for(i=0; i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d",&dato);
        array[i] = dato;
    }
}

void imprime_datos(int *array,int N){
    int i;
    printf("Total de datos: %d\n",N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
     }
}
```

destaco que el archivo txt tiene formato:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
...
```

¿Es correcto utilizar cmd de windows?, he visto que en mac utlizan ./lee_datos<datos_entrada.txt y el array se llena con los números dentro del archivo pero cuando hago ese mismo comando en CMD al parecer llena con números aleatorios y no es lo que busco (supongo que es por que C llena con datos al azar en memoria cuando no hay nada) y en powerShell tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando c que ya veo que si te recomiendo que no lo hagas con el cmd sino con la función `fgets();` y un puntero `FILE*` es más facil. Este sería el codigo para meter cada línea del archivo en un string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

void limpiar(char[]);

int main (){

setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish");//cambio la lengua a español para poder poner tildes.

int i;
char lectura[30][30]; //crea 30 strings que pueden almacenar 30 letras parav poner en cada uno una linea del archivo.
int contador = 0; //va a ir contando cuantas lineas se han leido y al final va a decir el total de letras leidas.
FILE *f; //creo un puntero hacia un archvo

f=fopen("archivo.txt","rt"); //El primer dato que pasas es el nombre del archivo que tiene que estar en la misma carpeta que el programa.
                             //El segundo dato que pasas es rt que significa leer texto (no puedes escribir) para escribir texto usa WT.

if(f != NULL) //si el archivo no existe f va a ser == NULL si existe leemos el programa
{

while( fgets(lectura[contador],30,f)) //Siempre y cuando no haya llegado al final del archivo sigue lellendo más lineas.
{                                     //fgets lee una linea del archivo y luego la siguiente vez que llamas la función lee la siguiente linea.

limpiar(lectura[contador]);//fgets siempre debuelve la variable con un '\n' al final con esta función lo quitamos.
contador=contador+1; //cada vez que lee una linea se suma uno a contador así la proxima kinea se guarda en otra variable que la anterior.
}

fclose(f);//cierro el archivo porque ya he acabado de leerlo.

for(i=0;i<contador;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",lectura[i]);
}

}
else //Si el archivo no exste da un aviso de error antes de cerrar el programa
{
    printf("El archivo no existe comprueba si está en la misma carpeta que el proograma.\n\n");
}
printf("\n\n");
system("pause");

return 0;
}

void limpiar(char frase[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++)//comprueba una por una todas las letras hasta que encuentra el \n
    {
        if(frase[i]=='\n')//si la letra por la que va es un \n lo cambia po \0 para así eliminarlo.
        {
            frase[i]='\0';
            return; //una vez que ha encontrado el \n no sigue buscando más se acaba la función.
        }
    }
}
```

si lo que quieres es meter números puedes usar la funcion `itoa` que sirve para cambiar de char a int y viene con la librería `string.h`. O también si quieres un solo número o solo una palabra puedes usar la función `fscanf();`.